# Error in `file.write`, wrong argument type

Tags: python

Using the CSV file of flowers again, fill in the gaps of the contents_of_file function to process the data without turning it into a dictionary. How do you skip over the header record with the field names?

```
import os
import csv
# Create a file with data in it
def create_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    fieldnames = ['type', 'name', 'color']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    file.write({'type': 'annual', 'name': 'carnation' , 'color': 'pink'})
    file.write({'type': 'perennial','name': 'daffodil' , 'color': 'yellow'})
    file.write({'type': 'perennial','name': 'iris' , 'color': 'blue'})
    file.write({'type': 'perennial','name': 'poinsettia' , 'color': 'red'})
    file.write({'type': 'annual', 'name': 'sunflower', 'color': 'yelolow'})
   # file.write("name,color,type\n")
    #file.write("carnation,pink,annual\n")
    #file.write("daffodil,yellow,perennial\n")
    #file.write("iris,blue,perennial\n")
    #file.write("poinsettia,red,perennial\n")
    #file.write("sunflower,yellow,annual\n")

# Read the file contents and format the information about each row
def contents_of_file(filename):
  return_string = ""

  # Call the function to create the file 
  create_file(filename)

  # Open the file
  with open('flowers.csv', 'r') as file:
    # Read the rows of the file
    rowss = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(rowss)
    if header != None:
      for row in rowss:
        # Format the return string for data rows only
        return_string = "a {} {} is {}\n".format(row['color'], row['name'], row['type'])
        print(return_string)


#Call the function

print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
```

it shows error as:

```
Error on line 42:
    print(contents_of_file("flowers.csv"))
Error on line 26:
    create_file(filename)
Error on line 9:
    file.write({'type': 'annual', 'name': 'carnation' , 'color': 'pink'})
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict
```

Comment: Did you read the error? You are trying to write a dictionary into a  file and it expects a string.

Comment: The title is so broad that it is basically misleading

Answer (score 0):

Change `file.write()` to `writer.writerow()`. `file` objects don't have a method that take in dictionaries. To write as dictionaries, use the `csv.DictWriter()` i.e. `writer` object instead.
Also, here:

```
with open('flowers.csv', 'r') as file:
```

I don't think you intend to hard-code the filename ad 'flowers.csv', you have already passed the filename as parameter to the `contents_of_file()` method.